# CSS display header and button in same line

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I've seen a few other threads about this issue but none seem to solve my problem. I have a header text and a button and I want to display them in the same line.

HTML:

```html
<div>
  <h3 class="header">Title</h3>
  <button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check header">Button</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.header {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

Now I'm using basically the same code later in my page except with `<img>'s` and it works perfectly fine. I thought that since I'm using `jQuery Mobile` maybe the styling is being overridden by that but even if I remove the `ui` classes the result is the same. Likewise, if I try to set a static width to both the header and the button I get the same result. Any help would be appreciated!

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/p9jf60yc/

Comment: you need to make your h3 an inline block. changing the containing div won't help anything.

Comment: the button.ui-btn class gets 100% width. so just set this to a less high value or overwrite it.

Comment: its the class .header not the tag "header" so this is correct Marc B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `ui-btn-inline` class to your button. It's part of the jQuery mobile CSS classes. No need to tweak with custom CSS.

```html
<div>
  <h3 class="header">Title</h3>
  <button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check header">Button</button>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/p9jf60yc/12/)

PS: an overview of all available classes can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_ref_css.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a width to the button, so it doesn't have the 100%:

```css
button.header {
  width: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p9jf60yc/2/

Answer (score 0):

Change the width on the button to auto.

```css
button.ui-btn {
  width: auto;
}
```